# Let $G$ be a group and let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ where $|H|=12$ and $|K|=5$. Show that $H\cap K = \{e\}$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ where $|H|=12$ and $|K|=5$. Show that  $H\cap  K = \{e\}$.

I used LaGrange's theorem to show that $|H|||G|$ and $|K|||G|$ so $12||G|$ and $5||G|$, and that $12$ and $5$ are relatively prime.  I'm not sure if this has gotten me closer to solving the problem, as I am stuck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

NOTE: This problem provides does not specifically define $e$, so I'm attempting to prove this assuming $e$ is the identity of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Consider $|H\cap K|\,|\,|H|$ and $|H\cap K|\,|\,|K|$.

Comment: Why am I allowed to say that?

Comment: By LaGrange's theorem, we have $|H\cap K|\,|\,|H|$.

Comment: Okay, so since |H∩K|||H| and |H∩K||K|, and |H| and |K| are relatively prime, then |H∩K| = 1 = e the identity of G.  But how do we know 1 = e?

Comment: $o(x)=1$ if and only if $x=e$. Some books use e instead of 1. Note that $e$ is the identity element.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in H\cap K$ then by Lagrange theorem the order of $x$ divides the two coprime orders: $|H|$ and $|K|$ so $o(x)=1$ and then $x=e$. Conclude.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $H\cap K$ has at least the element $e$. suppose that $H\cap K$ has another element $g$ so that $g\in H$ and $g\in K$. the $|H\cap K|$ divides the order of $H$ and $K$ but $5$ and $12$ don't have common divisors. So the only element in $H\cap K$ is $e$.